# Show SharePoint columns in Excel sheet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

How can one show columns from a SharePoint document library into an Excel sheet. Properly with VBA, but I don't now how?

Comment: Document libraries provide a default functionality of export to excel. Why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your list > in Ribbon and you will find export to excel option you can simply use it

Answer (score 0):

The Export to Exel option, export the whole library to Excel. I want to open the SharePoint item which is an Excel document and prompt certain SharePoint columns into the header....